# The case of JAVA classes causes errors

Tags: java

I am a beginner in JAVA
i meet a error。

> my java file named HelloWorld.java

- this demo have a error

```
class helloWorld {
    void p() {
        System.out.println("123123123");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        helloWorld h = new helloWorld();
        h.p();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: helloWorld)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:11)
```

- but i edit class name there will be no errors

```
class hello {
    void p() {
        System.out.println("123123123");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello h = new hello();
        h.p();
    }
}
```

When I was learning Java, the tutorial told me that Java classes are case-sensitive.
but why doesn't it work here.
i used jdk17

Comment: Looks to me like you're on an operating system with a case-insensitive filesystem so your OS can't store two copies of the class that differ only in case. Typically this means that if you saved a file with one case then try to save an updated version with a different case, the contents update but the filename doesn't, bringing them out of sync.

Comment: Easy thing to do is just delete all your `.class` files and then rebuild in a clean tree. And then switch to a sane operating system with case-sensitive filenames. :)

Comment: *"And then switch to a sane operating system with case-sensitive filenames."* - Or switch to a sane naming scheme for your classes where the names don't differ only by letter case.  For a start, the Java style guide says that a class name should not start with a lower case letter.

Comment: *"... the tutorial told me that Java classes are case-sensitive ..."* - It is not a good tutorial if it didn't mention class name style and the OS problem.  Consider finding a better one.

Comment: I am using window 10, trying to javac the java, then java the class  Produced same error.

Using visual studio code plugin java runs fine. 

It could be a window thing.

Comment: @Unmitigated If you follow the guys order of class position. You can reproduce the same error.

Comment: It >is< a Windows thing.  But the real solution is not to use classnames that differ only in case.   (The practical solution to "banging your head against a wall" is "stop doing it".)

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn - Not if they are not using Windows!  :-)

Comment: I've added a canonical duplink.  (It talks about a `class` and an `interface` whose names differ by case only.  But the answer applies to >all kinds< of named Java classes; i.e. `class`, `interface`, `enum`, `record`, `@interface` ...)

Answer (score 2):

Your first example has a single source file with two classes that differ only by the case of the first character: the package-private class `helloWorld` and the public class `HelloWorld`.  If the classes are loaded from .class files on the filesystem, and that filesystem is case-insensitive, then the attempt to load `HelloWorld.class` will likely access the file that was created for the `helloWorld` class, thus you get the error reported about the class name not matching what was expected.

When you changed the package-private class name to just `hello` the file in the filesystem would no longer collide with the file for `HelloWorld`, so there would be no conflict when trying to load the .class file and the correct file would be read.

Comment: [Java 21 _can warn_ for this](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/21-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8287885)